# What is asymptotic complexity for nested map traversal?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, big-o, complexity-theory

Suppose, I have such a data structure

```
NavigableMap<Long, NavigableMap<Long, Set<String> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

And I want to calculate the complexity for the algorithm below:

```
SortedSet<Widget> result = new TreeSet<>();
map.tailMap(first, true)
    .forEach( (k, v)-> {
        v.headMap(second, true)
                .forEach((key, value) -> result.addAll(value));
    });
```

This is correct, that complexity will be equal to

```
O(log (n + k) * (log (k + m) + log (m))) ?
```

Where

- n - count of elements in original *map*
- k - count of elements in *tailMap(first, true)*
- m - count of elements in *headMap(second, true)*

Comment: First of all I've noticed that there's something wrong with the types. It seems you're trying to `addAll` `Set<String>` to `SortedSet<Widget>`. Fix it please to make your question better.

Comment: You have two nested loops, the outer one one has *k* iterations, the inner one has *m* iterations (for each of the *k* iterations, with a different *m* every time, depending on the number of elements in these second-level maps). So should be `O(k*m)`. If you want to bound *k* and *m* to some *N* (maximum number of elements in all these maps), you get `O(N^2)`. But if there are some restrictions on `first` and `second` this could be lower.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for your reply. But I thought that  ```tailMap(first, true) .forEach ``` expression is equal to  ```O(log (n + k))```. 
I was guided by this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38868745/11698998. Is this answer wrong?

Comment: That answer says `O(log(n) + k)` which is much different from `O(log (n + k))`.

Comment: @Thilo thanks again! It was my mistake. It turns the complexity is even higher and equal to ```O(log (n) + k) * (log (k) + m)) ```?

Comment: Unless you have a reason to assume that the sizes of the submaps will not scale with the total size map, there is no need to distinguish between them for the Big O notation. So given size *n* and *m* for outer and inner map sizes, the time complexity is just `O(n + log n) * O(m + log m) `, as the worst case always is that the submap is as large as the entire map and as said, unless there’s a reason to assume that the average is different than somewhere between best and worst case for your scenario, there’s no point in formulating a different time complexity for it.

Comment: And `O(n + log n)` is the same as `O(n)`, so you end up with `O(n * m )`